# How to check existence of array of objects in ibm cloud object storage node js sdk and also copying multiple objects at a time to cos

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, object-storage

How to check existence of array of objects in ibm cloud object storage and also copying multiple objects at a time to cos using node js sdk(ibm-cos-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You can list objects with something like:

```
function doListObjects() {
    console.log('Listing Objects');
    return cos.listObjects({
        Bucket: bucket
    }).promise();
}

doListObject()
.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log('Finished!', process.exit());
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.error('An error occurred:');
    console.error(util.inspect(err));
});
```

Comment: I dont want list of objects. There are 1000's objects in cloud object storage and I have to array of 10 objects , i need to check whether they exist in cos. I cant loop through 1000s of objects in cos right? So any effective method to do this.